# Representation of symmetric tensors

Tags: linear-algebra, banach-spaces, tensor-products

For $X$ a Banach space, does every symmetric tensor $u$ in the projective tensor product $X \otimes X$ have a representation as:
$$
u = \alpha (a \otimes b) + \alpha (b \otimes a) + \beta (a \otimes a) + \gamma (b \otimes b)
$$
for some $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a, b \in X$?

I am reading a paper which suggests so, but it is stated without justification.

Comment: Not sure what exactly the "projective" tensor product means here, but in the simple case $X=\mathbb R^n$ it  is obviously wrong because it asserts every symmetric $n×n$ matrix $u$ can be written as the sum of 4 rank-1 matrices.

Comment: Why is the latter "obviously wrong"?

Comment: @daon The sum of 4 rank-1 matrices has rank at most $4$. However, there exist symmetric matrices that have rank greater than $4$.